# Is it possible to prevent command-line CatBoost to shuffle of the input data in cross-validation mode?

Tags: catboost

My data contains of 10 weeks observations. I would like to cross-validate the model in 9-to-1 week mode. So, I dont want CatBoost to shuffle the data before splitting. Is it possible with command line?

I'm not sure if "--cv-rand 0" (or any other value) works as "non shuffle".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `--cv-no-shuffle option`, it's just been implemented in catboost.

Answer (score 0):

Change parameter `stratified`

```
stratified = False
```